# Publish error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish

I keep getting this insane error which makes me think VS has gone stupid rather than wiser.

*Error  1   Copying file Content\Images\Brands\Lenovo.png to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Content\Images\Brands\Lenovo.png failed. Could not find file 'Content\Images\Brands\Lenovo.png'.      0   0   PriceCompare*

The error is produced when i try to publish to file system. It's stupid that VS is looking for a file which i deleted myself and it doesn't reside in the solution now.

Earlier too i was deleting and adding files but suddenly today the publish command has started giving errors.

In many of the other posts, i have seen people asking to open the .csproj file with notepad and remove the references to the deleted files manually. This seems very daunting as i have deleted a long list of files and added a lot of new ones.

**Is there an easier way to get rid of this problem or i need to manually remove the references to deleted file. Can't i just delete the obj folder or empty the bin directory or clean solution or something.**

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to tell Visual Studio that you deleted the files.

Go to the project/solution folder where the files existed and remove them there.

Visual Studio assumes that since you *added* the file originally, it should be published. It can't assume that you don't want it just because it isn't in the filesystem. Think about using source control in a team - the file may only exist in one persons's machine, but still be needed.

This is not a difficult as you think - the files that can not be found have a semi-transparent look to them, easy enough to select these and bulk delete in Visual Studio. You can also set the project properties to display all files then select all the ones that need to be part of the project and add them in a single operation.

Comment: god bless you mate....in just 5 lines you have summed up a lot and made me understand how stupid i was to blame VS :-) ... thanks!! you are a live saver...

Comment: yaa.....you are right they are not difficult to spot (i know about the inclusion and exclusion of files :-P , but was being a little stupid)....actually those folders were not expanded so i couldn't see the deleted files....i manually removed them from file system.

Comment: I had to actually open the VS solution and remove the xml tags

Answer (score 14):

This basically happens whenever we delete the contents from the folder but forget to remove from Visual studio solutions.

To Resolve this follow below steps:-

1. Go to visual studio solution explorer and right click on the specific content
2. exclude from project.
3. right click and remove from visual studio solution explorer.

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Totally the right answer and a perfect clean solution... It works after deleting

Answer (score 3):

I ran into same issue because project files were **added** and **removed** so many times. Me just removed **yellow marked file** from **visual studio solution** & it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Problem with access permissions, I run VS in Administrator mode(Run as Administrator). Did the Trick.

Comment: Did the trick for me too. Weird, didn't have to do it earlier... :/
Still thx :)

Answer (score 2):

Shows this message when you delete a file but its name still remains in the project. Locate the file shown in the message. Then delete it.

[image: Look at the picture]

Answer (score 0):

In some cases:

- delete app folder in `bin` and try to re-publish

or

- in `.csproj` file check if the project version is same as the version in VS project property.